# Extending Docker JBoss WildFly server not working

Tags: docker, jboss, kubernetes

Hope doing good all.

Env: centos 7.3.1611, kubernetes : 1.5, docker 1.12

Problem 1 : Extended jboss docker not working but docker image created successfully

POD gets an error see below, step 7.

Problem 2 : Once problem #1 fixed then i wish to upload to docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/

how can i upload steps please if possible.

```
            1) pull 

            docker pull jboss/wildfly

            2) vi Dockerfile

            FROM jboss/wildfly
            RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin123$ --silent
            CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]

            3) Extend docker image
            docker build --tag=nbasetty/wildfly-server .

            4) [root@centos7 custom-jboss]# docker images
            REPOSITORY                                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
            nbasetty/wildfly-server                               latest              c1fbb87faffd        43 minutes ago      583.8 MB
            docker.io/httpd                                       latest              e0645af13ada        2 weeks ago         177.5 MB


            5)vi jboss-wildfly-rc-service-custom.yaml

            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Service
            metadata:
              name: wildfly-service
            spec:
              externalIPs:
                - 10.0.2.15
              selector:
                app: wildfly-rc-pod
              ports:
                - name: web
                  port: 8080
                #- name: admin-console
                #  port: 9990
              type: LoadBalancer
            ---
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: ReplicationController
            metadata:
              name: wildfly-rc
            spec:
              replicas: 2
              template:
                metadata:
                  labels:
                    app: wildfly-rc-pod
                spec:
                  containers:
                  - name: wildfly
                    image: nbasetty/wildfly-server
                    ports:
                    - containerPort: 8080
                    #- containerPort: 9990

            6) kubectl create -f jboss-wildfly-rc-service-custom.yaml
            7) [root@centos7 jboss]# kubectl get pods
            NAME               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
            mysql-pvc-pod      1/1       Running            6          2d
            wildfly-rc-d0k3h   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          23m
            wildfly-rc-hgsfj   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          23m

            [root@centos7 jboss]# kubectl logs wildfly-rc-d0k3h
            Error from server (BadRequest): container "wildfly" in pod 
            "wildfly-rc-d0k3h" is waiting to start: 
            trying and failing to pull image
```

Comment: what is your kubernetes configuration? how many nodes your have in the cluster?

Comment: single node (master, slave) - experimental

Comment: I assume your creating the docker image on the slave node. can you post this output ' kubectl get pods -o wide'

Comment: I tried your steps in my environment. it works

Comment: But i am getting an error message,  "ImagePullBackOff" Error
I created a local registry and uploaded to my local registry then it worked. my `pod` points to local registry as image : localhost:5000/wildfly-server

Answer (score 0):

Glad you have found a way to make it working. here is step I followed.

1. I labeled node-01 as 'dbserver: mysql'
2. create the docker image in node-01
3. created this pod, it worked.

```
apiVersion: v1 kind: ReplicationController metadata:   name: wildfly-rc spec:   replicas: 2   template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wildfly-rc-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wildfly
        image: nbasetty/wildfly-server
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      nodeSelector:
        dbserver: mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-creating the issue:

```
docker pull jboss/wildfly

mkdir jw
cd jw
echo 'FROM jboss/wildfly
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin123$ --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]' | tee Dockerfile

docker build --tag=docker.io/surajd/wildfly-server .
```

See the images available:

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/surajd/wildfly-server                          latest              10e96902ea12        11 seconds ago      583.8 MB
```

Create a config that works:

```
echo '
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wildfly
spec:
  selector:
    app: wildfly
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wildfly
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wildfly
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wildfly
        image: docker.io/surajd/wildfly-server
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
' | tee config.yaml
kubectl create -f config.yaml
```

Notice the field `imagePullPolicy: Never`, this helps you use the image available on the node(the image we built using `docker build`). This works on single node cluster but may or may not work on multiple node cluster. So not recommended to put that value, but since we are doing experiment on single node cluster we can set it to `Never`. Always set it to `imagePullPolicy: Always`. So that whenever the pod is scheduled the image will be pulled from registry. Read about [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) and some config related [tips](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images).

Now to pull the image from registry the image should be on registry, so to answer your question of pushing it to docker hub run command:

```
docker push docker.io/surajd/wildfly-server
```

So in the above example replace `surajd` with your docker registry username.

---

Here are steps I used to do setup of single node cluster on CentOS:

My machine version:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

Here is what I have done:

Setup single node k8s cluster on CentOS as follows ([src1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) & [src2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)):

```
yum update -y
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
        https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
setenforce 0
yum install -y docker kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni
systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet

sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
kubeadm init


cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf

kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Now k8s version:

```
# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T18:44:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T18:33:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```